# What is the difference between a theorem and an axiom?

Tags: definition, foundations

What is the main difference between a law and an axiom? Suddenly this question arose in my mind. For example in mathematics I have heard many theorems in my school life like Bayes’ theorom, Pythagoras’ theorem, basic proportionality theorem, etc... and also heard about axioms like Euclid's axioms. But what is the main difference between these two?

Comment: Yes, it has answered my question